# Getting Kinect V2 (Kinect for Windows) to work with skeleton tracking on Windows 7. Is it possible?

Tags: image-processing, windows-7, kinect, openkinect

The title says it all. We're making a small academic project with skeleton tracking using Kinect V2, and our industrial partner asked us if it was possible to run it on Windows 7. I've managed to run openkinect2 on Ubuntu once before, but I'm struggling to find a way to use Kinect V2 for skeleton tracking using anything other than Kinect SDK 2.0.

I tried OpenNI2, but after quite some time I realized it's actually not for Kinect V2...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you install .NET framework 4.5.2 with Windows 7?

Comment: If you are able to do that, and then run Kinect SDK... you might be able to use it...

Comment: Seems to me that Windows 8 is a minimum requirement for Kinect V2 SDK to run. The minimum .NET framework version is not listed. Apparently, it has something to do with usb 3 drivers in Windows 8. Therefore, I'm hoping to complete this project without using the official SDK altogether

Comment: If you are able to go through it let me know! good luck

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this might be my best shot:
https://github.com/joaquimrocha/Skeltrack